# MySQL - Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

what am I doing wrong with this query:

```
INSERT INTO 'stats' ('uuid', 'kills', 'deaths', 'games', 'beststreak') VALUES ('5dbef8c9-977a-3ddf-b732-473be6318596', '0', '0', '0', '0')
```

Here you can see the strutcture of my table:
[image: http://puu.sh/9F59D/3820d07c83.png]

The error:

```
[15:11:23 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stats' ('uuid', 'kills', 'deaths', 'games','beststreak') VALUES ('5dbef8c9-977' at line 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table and column names should be enclosed either in backticks, or left alone. They shouldn't be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Also, since the last 4 columns are type **`INT`**, you don't need to pass `0` as strings either.

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (
    `uuid`,
    `kills`,
    `deaths`,
    `games`,
    `beststreak`
)
VALUES (
    '5dbef8c9-977a-3ddf-b732-473be6318596',
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the quotes around your table name and column identifiers. Use ticks or nothing.

```
INSERT INTO stats (uuid, kills, deaths, games, beststreak) 
VALUES ('5dbef8c9-977a-3ddf-b732-473be6318596', '0', '0', '0', '0')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`uuid`, `kills`, `deaths`, `games`, `beststreak`) 
VALUES ('5dbef8c9-977a-3ddf-b732-473be6318596', '0', '0', '0', '0')
```